# How to clear data in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to C#. How to Clear data in `DataGridView`?

I have some `data` in `datagridview` and I have one `drop down box` at every `index` changed

I want `datagrid view` will be changed. but I did not get the solution just i Added to

previous data can any one help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the DataGridView change when the Dropdownlist change so u just reuse the Code grant value to Datagridview.

Answer (score 4):

if you use data source to fill the grid use:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=null;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

if you fill the grid programmatically use:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```